# Search String Value placemarker in Google Earth API KML File?

Tags: c#, javascript, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Trying to create search box for `Google Earth API` Plugin for javascript
I am able to parse `KMLFile` and load in GE API and now I have to embed search by Placemarker name loaded by KML.

Code using Lat & Long

```
var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
lookAt.set(point.y, point.x, 600, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 00, 0);
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

Is there any possibility for `LookAt` using Placemarker Name (string value) instead searching of  using LAT, LONG?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a few ways to do this depending on your set-up.

One general way would be to give each placemark a unique ID, then use that ID to look at it.

For example, imagine you have the following kml placemark and that you have loaded into the api from the url `http://localhost/foo.kml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark id="myPlacemark">
    <name>Myplacemark</name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

You could then 'look at' the placemark `myPlacemark` like so.

```
var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl('http://localhost/foo.kml#myPlacemark');
var point = placemark.getGeometry();
var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
lookAt.set(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude(), 600, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 00, 0);
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

A simple function could be made so you can simply pass the correct ID in to look at any point placemark loaded from KML that has an ID.

```
var myLookAt = function(id) {
  var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl(id);
  if('getGeometry' in placemark && 
    placemark.getGeometry().getType() == 'KmlPoint') {
    var point = placemark.getGeometry();
    var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
    lookAt.set(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude(), 600, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 00, 0);
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
  }
};

// useage
myLookAt('http://localhost/foo.kml#myPlacemark');
```

You could obviously alter the `myLookAt` function to look for `lookAt` and `camera` elements, or to handle other types of objects as well - such as multi geometries, etc.